# invariance by deformation of $H^1(dlog)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety. The canonical morphism of sheaves
$dlog:{\cal O}_X^*\to \Omega_X$ defines a map   $c:Pic(X)\to H^1(\Omega_X)$.
Is this map invariant by deformation ? (i.e if $({\cal L_s})_{s\in S}$ is a family of line bundles on $X$ parametrized by a smooth curve $S$, is $c({\cal L}_s)$ independent of $s$ ?).

Comment: In char 0 and $X$ smooth, this should follow from the fact that the first Chern class (your $c$) is a topological invariant (after reducing to $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: The hypotheses don't say that $X$ is projective. Could something go wrong with non-projective varieties, even when we are smooth and in characteristic zero? @DonuArapura

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yes, I tacitly assumed that $X$ is proper as well. In general, $H^1(\Omega_X^1)$ might be infinite dimensional, so then I'm not sure what happens.

Comment: @DonuArapura,   In fact I am interested in non reduced varieties. And I would like to know if there is a more direct proof in the case of smooth projective varieties (without the use of topology), for example using Cech cohomology.

Comment: It works if the family (i.e. $S$) is projective of course, because in this case we get a morphism  $S\to H^1(\Omega_X)$ which must be constant.

Comment: Infinitesimally, deformations of line bundles come from $H^1(\mathcal{O})$. So this should come down to the statement that $d : H^1(\mathcal{O}) \to H^1(\Omega^1)$ is $0$ which, as I recall, has no easy proof.

Comment: @David E Speye   Yes, I tried this also. And it is not easy. A way to prove it is to see if two line bundles in a component of $Pic(X)$ can be connected by a projective curve. Unfortunately this is not true for non smooth varieties.

Comment: How about $X=(\mathbf{A}^2\setminus \{0,0\})\times \operatorname{Spec}(k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$? The map $H^1(\mathcal{O})\to H^1(\Omega^1_X)$ is nonzero for the punctured plane, and its trivial first order thickening $X$ has plenty of line bundles. I didn't check the details, but this is the example I would try first.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger More generally we can take  $X=M\times Spec(k(\epsilon)/\epsilon^2))$. We have then decompositions :  $H^1({\cal O}_X)=H^1({\cal O}_M)\times \epsilon H^1({\cal O}_M)$, $H^1(\Omega_X)=H^1(\Omega_M)\times\epsilon H^1(\Omega_M)\times H^1({\cal O}_M).d\epsilon$. The tangent map of David E Speyer, $d:H^1({\cal O}_X)\to H^1(\Omega_X)$, has then a component   $ \epsilon H^1({\cal O}_M)\to H^1({\cal O}_M).d\epsilon$ (the identity), which is non zero if $H^1({\cal O}_X)$ is non zero. So in this case the answer of my question is : no.